# MATLAB: Break up image into image blocks, then undo this operation

Tags: matlab, reshape, permute

I am using the following line of code to break up an image into blocks (sub-regions):

```
srhblocks = reshape(permute(reshape(im2, ysrh, ynum, xsrh, xnum), [1 3 2 4]), ysrh, xsrh, xnum * ynum);
```

x/ysrh and x/ynum is length and number of blocks in x/y

I then perform an operation on each image block (which outputs one number per block) and then want to undo the above reshape. How do you perform the opposite to above? Thanks

Comment: Do you HAVE to reshape the image in order to get your calculation or would it be enough to simply get the sub-region for the calculation and leave the image as it it?

Comment: What is the size of `im`? A specific reason not to use `blocproc` here? What is the size of the output of from your calculation and what size do you expect as a final result?

Comment: size(im2) = 357 x 441. This generates srhblocks which is 119x49x27 pixels so there are 27 119x49 pixel blocks. I want to reshape this into a 3D stack with 9(x) x 3(y) 2D images

Comment: I believe I cannot use blocproc as I am calculating a normalised cross correlation using each sub-region block.

Comment: @2one - sure you can.  Just supply an anonymous function to `blockproc` that computes the normalized cross correlation of each block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%stitch together search image blocks
srhblocksall = num2cell(srhblocks, [1 2]); %split the stack into a cell array 
srhblocksall = reshape(srhblocksall, ynum, xnum); %reshape the tiles into their final position.
srhblocksall = cell2mat(srhblocksall); %convert to matrix
```

The code above worked for my application.